# Distribution involving orthogonal matrix

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, orthogonal

If $Y∼N(\mu,I\sigma^2)$ and $Q$ is any orthogonal matrix of appropriate dimension, how do I find the distribution of $QY$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $QY$ is just a rotation and/or flip of the original basis space. So the magnitude of the mean shouldn't change. The covariance of $Y$ is just a scaled identity matrix hence the transformation won't change the covariance structure at all. We end up with $QY \sim N(Q\mu, \sigma^2 I)$, where $||\mu|| = ||Q\mu||$